# How to edit a cell title / label in Numbers?

Tags: mac, numbers, formatting

I started a new sheet using the "Simple Budget" template on the Mac. I edited the text values of the cells and changed the numbers' column format to be just Number.

All good but when I created a formula I noticed that some of the cells have a title or label, I assume pre-existing in the template. So for example, my formula is

`=B3 * B2 / 100`

but what I get is actually

`=Income::B3 * B2 / 100`

The text "Income" is nowhere (that I can see) in my current spreadsheet, and I can't find a way to edit this cell label or title, where do I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

My formula gets the table title when I reference a cell from an external table in a formula. Table titles were not visible (Table Options > activate Title to see it) and that *table* was called **Income**, thus the reference in my formula.

I see now that I can change the title of the table, and that reference will always be there if I call a cell in a formula inside another table.